# DB issues on different environment Heroku

Tags: mysql, postgresql, laravel, heroku, laravel-4

I'm developing a new application with Laravel 4, i have add a new [package](https://bitbucket.org/hailwoodnz/database-config-loader/overview) and everything is working fine on local. But troubles start while i'm pushing to my Heroku app. I first had to force migrate and seed (Heroku toolbelt return me "Command cancelled") but finally success. The db in production run under pgsql while local is MySQL.

I'm experiencing issues in production, here's the exception :

> SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "production" does not exist LINE 1: ..." in (select COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN environment = "productio... ^ (SQL: select * from "dbconfig_settings" where "id" in (select COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN environment = "production" THEN id END), MIN(id)) from "dbconfig_settings" group by "package", "key") and "package" is null and "group" = general) (View: /app/app/views/layout/main.blade.php)

Here's the line that fail :

> {{ DBconfig::get('general.site_name') }}

And here's the sql log for the local :

> select * from `dbconfig_settings` where `id` in (select COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN  environment = "local" THEN id END), MIN(id)) from `dbconfig_settings` group by `package`,  `key`) and `package` is null and `group` = 'general'

Thanks and merry xmas !